# OpenGL/Glut: Making the camera rotate around X axis with arrow keys?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, opengl-compat

I'm trying to make the gluLookAt() function so that when I press the up & down key the camera moves around the X axis

I'm trying a method I saw at: http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glut-tutorial/keyboard-example-moving-around-the-world/
but it's not working for me. Anyone knows an easier way? and where should I put the gluLookAt() so on myDisplay() func?

```
#include"glut.h"
#include<cmath>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

float xr = 0, yr = 0; //to control the object's movement from left to right

// actual vector representing the camera's direction
float lx = 0.0f, lz = -1.0f;
// XZ position of the camera
float x = 0.0f, z = 5.0f;

GLfloat angle = 0.0f;
int refreshmill = 1;

void timer(int value) { //to control the rotation of the object
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(refreshmill, timer, 0);
}

void myDisplay(void) {
    //Circle One
    float theta;
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glPushMatrix();
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    for (int x = 0; x < 360; x++) {
        theta = x * 3.142 / 180;
        glVertex2f(150 * cos(theta)+xr,150 * sin(theta)+yr);
    }
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();

    //Circle Two
    float theta2;
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // rotation
    glRotatef(angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, -0.5f); // rotation
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 1);
    for (int x = 0; x < 360; x++) {
        theta2 = x * 3.142 / 180;
        glVertex2f(150 + 15 * cos(theta2) + xr, 15 * sin(theta2) + yr);
    }
    glutSwapBuffers();
    angle += 0.2; // rotation
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();

    //Draw Star
    glColor3ub(119, 193, 15);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glPushMatrix();
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2d(15+xr, 60+yr);
    glVertex2d(75+xr, 75+yr); //right peak
    glVertex2d(15+xr, 90+yr);
    glVertex2d(0+xr, 150+yr); //Up-peak Changed
    glVertex2d(-15+xr, 90+yr);
    glVertex2d(-75+xr,75+yr);
    glVertex2d(-15+xr, 60+yr);
    glVertex2d(0+xr,0+yr);
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
    glFlush();
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutSwapBuffers();

}

void renderScene(void) {

    // Clear Color and Depth Buffers

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Reset transformations
    glLoadIdentity();
    // Set the camera
    gluLookAt(x, 1.0f, z,
        x + lx, 1.0f, z + lz,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    // Draw ground
    glColor3f(0.9f, 0.9f, 0.9f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(-100.0f, 0.0f, -100.0f);
    glVertex3f(-100.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f);
    glVertex3f(100.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f);
    glVertex3f(100.0f, 0.0f, -100.0f);
    glEnd();

    myDisplay();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

//Move to left or right
void keyboard(int key, int x, int y) {

    float fraction = 0.1f;

    switch (key) {
    case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
        xr++;
        cout << x << endl;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;

    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
        xr--;
        cout << x << endl;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;

    case GLUT_KEY_UP:
        angle -= 0.01f;
        lx = sin(angle);
        lz = -cos(angle);
        break;

    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
        angle += 0.01f;
        lx = sin(angle);
        lz = -cos(angle);
        break;
    }
}

void init() {
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(-250, 250, -250, 250); //IMPORTANT- Define from negative to positive
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // init GLUT and create window
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("Homework: Circle");
    // register callbacks
    glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);
    glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);
    glutIdleFunc(renderScene);
    glutTimerFunc(0,timer,0);
    glutSpecialFunc(keyboard);
    // OpenGL init
    init();
    // enter GLUT event processing cycle
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there should be only 1 display call back function:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    // [...]

    // glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay); <----- DELETE!!!
    glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);

    // glutIdleFunc(renderScene);  <----- DELETE!!!

    // [...]
}
```

Setup an an orthographic projection with an extended near and far plane. If the object is rotated around the X axis, it takes space in the 3 dimensions:

```cpp
void init() {
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-250, 250, -250, 250, -250, 250); // <----
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

Add a variable `anglaX` which is changed in the keyboard event:

```cpp
float angleX = 0.0f;
```

```cpp
void keyboard(int key, int x, int y) {

    switch (key) {
        case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT: xr++; break;
        case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:  xr--; break;
        case GLUT_KEY_UP:    angleX -= 1.0f; break;
        case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:  angleX += 1.0f; break;
    }
}
```

Rotate the model, after the view was set:

```cpp
gluLookAt(x, 0.0f, z, x, 0.0f, z-1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(angleX, 1, 0, 0);
```

Don't do any calls to `glutSwapBuffers()`, `glFlush()` and `glutPostRedisplay()`, except at the end of `renderScene`:

```cpp
void timer(int value) { //to control the rotation of the object
    // glutPostRedisplay(); <--- DELETE
    glutTimerFunc(refreshmill, timer, 0);
}
```

```cpp
void myDisplay(void) {
    //Circle One
    float theta;
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1, 0, 0);

    glPushMatrix();
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    for (int x = 0; x < 360; x++) {
        theta = x * 3.142 / 180;
        glVertex2f(150 * cos(theta)+xr,150 * sin(theta)+yr);
    }
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();

    //Circle Two
    float theta2;

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // rotation
    glRotatef(angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, -0.5f); // rotation
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 1);
    for (int x = 0; x < 360; x++) {
        theta2 = x * 3.142 / 180;
        glVertex2f(150 + 15 * cos(theta2) + xr, 15 * sin(theta2) + yr);
    }

    angle += 0.2; // rotation
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();

    //Draw Star
    glColor3ub(119, 193, 15);

    glPushMatrix();
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2d(15+xr, 60+yr);
    glVertex2d(75+xr, 75+yr); //right peak
    glVertex2d(15+xr, 90+yr);
    glVertex2d(0+xr, 150+yr); //Up-peak Changed
    glVertex2d(-15+xr, 90+yr);
    glVertex2d(-75+xr,75+yr);
    glVertex2d(-15+xr, 60+yr);
    glVertex2d(0+xr,0+yr);
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

```cpp
void renderScene(void) {

    // Clear Color and Depth Buffers
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Reset transformations
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    // Set the camera
    gluLookAt(x, 0.0f, z, x, 0.0f, z-1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(angleX, 1, 0, 0);

    // Draw ground
    glColor3f(0.9f, 0.9f, 0.9f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(-100.0f, 0.0f, -100.0f);
    glVertex3f(-100.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f);
    glVertex3f(100.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f);
    glVertex3f(100.0f, 0.0f, -100.0f);
    glEnd();

    myDisplay();

    glFlush();
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Further I recommend to use double buffering:

```cpp
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can init your camera with `gluLookAt` at `init()`, then rotate it when arrow keys pressed. If you want to rotate camera around it's local x axis, assume your initial modelview matrix is `V`, newly happened rotation around x axis is `R`, you need to set modelview matrix to `R*V`, not `V*R`.

```
 case GLUT_KEY_UP:
       GLfloat temp[16];
       glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, temp);
       glLoadIdentity();
       glRotate(stepAngle, 1, 0, 0); // calculate stepAngle by your self
       glMultMatrixf(temp);
       break;
```

You don need to reset modelview matrix during rendering, view part is already done, make sure you restore it after rendering the whole scene:

```
glPushMatrix(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)
// don't call glLoadIdentity() here, you don't need to reset view part.
...
...
glPopMatrix()
```

Comment: No don't do any transformations in events. Do the transformation in the render function only!

Comment: Could you tell me why? Or give me a link. I'm having trouble with google today.

Comment: It makes it inflexible and hard to understand. Further there is not any chance to port the code to something else then legacy OpenGL, which is deprecated for decades. The goal has to be to set a projection matrix, view matrix and model matrix at one point in the code.